# Entendendo o mesmo método no repository e no service

Tags: jpa

Por que no service e no controller, os objetos apontam para a mesma função? Vou detalhar:

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface AtividadeRepository extends CrudRepository<Atividade, Integer> {
    Atividade findByNome(String nome); //até aqui tudo bem.
}
```

service:

```
public Iterable<Atividade> findAll() {
   return atividadeRepository.findAll();
}

//Retorna todas as atividades, até aqui tudo bem.
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Iterable<Atividade>> listAll() {
    Iterable<Atividade> atividades;
    atividades = atividadeService.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<Atividade>>(atividades, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Por que além de usar o mesmo método, tem também o retorno?

O controller não pode pegar do objeto do repository e mandar para a view ao invés de fazer a "busca" e retornar? Ou a linha:

```
    return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<Atividade>>(atividades, HttpStatus.OK);
```

só retorna o status?

Sei que tem a questão de reaproveitamento de código, mas fazendo a mesma busca, acho redundante.

Ou será que eu estou totalmente por fora?

Answer (score 1):

## Por que além de usar o mesmo método, tem também o retorno?

Não é bem o mesmo método. Como você está usando uma aplicação multicamada, para este exemplo, pode parecer que é a mesma coisa, mas não é.

O repositório serve para manipular coleções de alguma forma. O serviço harmoniza as relações entre repositórios diferentes.

## O *controller* não pode pegar do objeto do *repository* e mandar para a *view* ao invés de fazer a "busca" e retornar?

Você até pode excluir a camada de serviço para esta etapa e eliminar uma parte prolixa, mas isso provavelmente faria seu projeto ficar fora do padrão, visto que a camada de serviço pode ser usada em outras etapas do sistema.

## Sei que tem a questão de reaproveitamento de código, mas fazendo a mesma busca, acho redundante.

Não é só você.